# Connecting GNU R to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, r

I have `GNU R` installed (the `S-like` statistics package; version 2.8.1) and `PostgreSQL (8.4.1)`, but I cannot connect `GNU R` to my `RDBMS`.

When I first did this (years ago - code lost) `DBI` for `R` didn't exist. Now it does. I am also confused as to which `R` package to use. A quick search returns:

- [RPostgreSQL](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RPostgreSQL/) seems to be the most up-to-date
- `RPgSQL` Looks abandoned. I wish they would put a date on their webpage. ;-(

My `Linux distribution` doesn't package `R` packages (irony) but I am comfortable running `R CMD INSTALL package.tar.gz`.

I installed `RPostgreSQL`: a lot of documentation says to call `dbConnect` but I get the following error message: `Error: object "dbConnect" not found`.

Comment: "You're my only hope" is nonsense. There is a dedicated mailing list called r-sig-db for R and databases.

Comment: Don't worry Dirk, I think it's just a harmless 'Star Wars' reference.

Answer (score 9):

Just for completeness, you have two more options

- [**RODBC**](http://c) which is very mature and feature-complete but doesn't correspond to the DBI framework as the PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQLite, Oracle, ... interfaces do. You also need to fiddle with ODBC setup files which can be tricky. But ODBC may be useful for other data access uses too.
- [**RdbiPgSQL**](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/bioc/html/RdbiPgSQL.html) from the BioConductor project which is also mature but uses yet another protocol that was to compete with DBI and never took of. This PostgreSQL package is featureful though.

But as a [**RPostgreSQL**](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RPostgreSQL) maintainer/co-author I am glad you found this one.  As the other poster suggested, try `library(RPostgreSQL)` before issueing commands.  If you encounter other problems, feel free to email me off-SO with a bug report.

*Edit*: There is another option of embedding R inside PostgreSQL using Joe Conway's [**PL/R**](http://www.joeconway.com/plr/).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you need to run `require(RPostgreSQL)` before you can use `dbConnect`?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you need to install the DBI package (most database packages depend on it).

If you use `install.packages('RPpostgreSQL',dep=TRUE)` from within R it should take care of any dependency issues.

Answer (score 0):

RODBC works great for me. You just have to set up a data source name (DSN) for the database you want to connect to. I find this nice because then the specific connection info does not have to be stored in R, and it may vary for your collaborators.

Also, yes, it sounds like you haven't loaded the RPostgresSQL package.